# Where does Remmina store fingerprints/thumbprints of the RDP connections to remote machines?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, certificates, remmina

I couldn't find where `Remmina` stores fingerprints/thumbprints of the RDP connections to remote machines.

I've tried:

1. `$HOME/.config/remmina/`
2. `$HOME/.local/share/remmina`
3. `$HOME/.ssh`
4. Searching the web... no luck.

And then I found it - sharing here to save your time - see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023-08 (*buntu 20.04), It's here:

```
cat $HOME/.config/freerdp/known_hosts*
```